# self.sendClickEvent(cev[0]): error when mouseReleaseEvent

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqtgraph

My code is like below. When I double click, I get error like above. What should I do in this case?

I found some clues

1. http://www.pyqtgraph.org/documentation/_modules/pyqtgraph/GraphicsScene/mouseEvents.html#MouseClickEvent.double
2. http://python.6.x6.nabble.com/problem-with-mouseDoubleClickEvent-on-QTreeView-1-td1921227.html

I guess pg.Plotwidget doesn't have 'mouseDoubleClickEvent', so problem may be inherit class...

```
from PyQt5 import QtGui
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

import pyqtgraph as pg

class MyPlot(pg.PlotWidget):
    def mouseDoubleClickEvent(self, ev):
        print(1)

class main(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        pw = MyPlot() 
        pw.showGrid(x=True, y=True)
        pw.setXRange(0, 10)
        x = range(0, 10)
        y = [2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20]
        layout = QHBoxLayout()
        pw.plot(x, y, pen='b', symbol='x', symbolPen='g', symbolBrush=0.2, name='green')
        layout.addWidget(pw)
        self.setLayout(layout)
        self.show()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setAttribute(Qt.AA_Use96Dpi)
    main = main()
    main.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pyqtgraph\GraphicsScene\GraphicsScene.py", line 199, in mouseReleaseEvent
    if self.sendClickEvent(cev[0]):
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: sorry for that. I add some example and comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that overriding the mouseDoubleClickEvent method and not calling the parent method through super causes the event transmitted to the other methods that use it to be None such as mouseReleaseEvent causing the error. The solution is to call the parent's method using super.

```
class MyPlot(pg.PlotWidget):
    def mouseDoubleClickEvent(self, ev):
        print(1)
        super().mouseDoubleClickEvent(ev)
```

It can be considered a bug that pyqtgraph does not foresee this case, and it seems that pyqtgraph developers already know about it since they have solved it in the develop branch of pyqtgraph so another solution is to use that code and for this you can install it using the following procedure:

```
git clone -b develop git@github.com:pyqtgraph/pyqtgraph.git
sudo python setup.py install
```

Comment: It is solved, you are right. Really thanks for reply and the additional explain too :)